# Getting Date as null when using java.sql.Date

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to insert the date into database and I am using java.sql.Date but the problem when user is submitting the form I am getting Null value. As per some restriction I am only allowed to use java.sql.Date not util.Date.

Entity

```
    import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="User_ID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name="User_first_name")
    @NotEmpty(message="Field cannot be left blank")
    private String First_Name;

    @Column(name="user_last_name")
    private String Last_Name;

    @Column(name="user_contact")
    private int Contact;

    @Column(name="user_email")
    private String Email;

    @Column(name="user_date_birth")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date DateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="user_joining_date")
    private Date DateOfJoining;

    @Column(name="user_salary")
    @NotNull
    private int Salary;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name() {
        return First_Name;
    }

    public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
        First_Name = first_Name;
    }

    public String getLast_Name() {
        return Last_Name;
    }

    public void setLast_Name(String last_Name) {
        Last_Name = last_Name;
    }

    public int getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public void setContact(int contact) {
        Contact = contact;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return DateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Date getDateOfJoining() {
        return DateOfJoining;
    }

    public void setDateOfJoining(Date dateOfJoining) {
        DateOfJoining = dateOfJoining;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        Salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
    package com.example.crud;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.example.crud.entities.Users;
import com.example.crud.service.TaskService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService service;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        System.out.println("exe");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(java.sql.Date.class,"DateOfBirth", new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/Add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Map<String, Object> model){
        Users users = new Users();
        model.put("users", users);
        logger.debug("users");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Register(@ModelAttribute("users") Users users, BindingResult result, Model model){
        System.out.println(users.getFirst_Name());
        System.out.println(users.getDateOfBirth());
//      service.Register(users);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Comment: When you use Date.class, you should specify the fully qualified name, e.g java.sql.Date

Comment: I specified the package name at the beginning. Is this really matter ?

Comment: It's worth a try, I can't really see anything else that could be wrong other than the date format or the field name.

Comment: Put some loggers and debug it to see where is your date getting null

Comment: And start by explaining what you mean by "getting null value".

Comment: Null means "null"

Comment: I think @chrylis was more focused on the "getting" part, obviously. How are _getting_ the value? As for which package you imported, that should have been in your posted code so no one has to ask or guess. When you post an incomplete example, the problem is often in the code you didn't share.

Comment: I posted the full code. again main issue is when user is submitting the for via jsp in the controller I am getting null of date column.

Comment: `CustomDateEditor` is valid for `java.util.Date`, not for `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @alfcope then what should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Register your own custom editor.

```
public class SqlDateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    private DateFormat dateFormat;

    public SqlDateEditor (final DateFormat dateFormat)
    {
      this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        try {
            setValue(new java.sql.Date(this.dateformat.parse(text).getTime())
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse date: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        java.sql.Date value = (java.sql.Date) getValue();
        return (value != null ? this.dateFormat.format(value) : "");
    }
}
```

At your controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(java.sql.Date.class, new SqlDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")));
}
```